# searching in table by "person Id " in form1 and display information on labels of form2

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, modal-dialog

I have two forms: Form1 and Form2.
Form1 contains one textbox and one search button. When I click on that button, form 2 must be load then the name and family of that person who was searched in form 1, would display on labels.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

by my code, information of person, display on form1 but not on form2.

form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tbl1BindingSource.SuspendBinding();

    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'region1003660DataSet.Tbl1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tbl1TableAdapter.Fill(this.region1003660DataSet.Tbl1);

    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(tbl1BindingSource.ToString());
        int find = tbl1BindingSource.Find("id", txtSearch.Text);
        if (find >= 0)
        {
            tbl1BindingSource.ResumeBinding();
            tbl1BindingSource.Position = find;
        }
        else tbl1BindingSource.SuspendBinding();
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(find);
        f2.Show();
      
    }
}
```

form2:

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(int f)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tbl1BindingSource.SuspendBinding();
        tbl1BindingSource.Position = f;
    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'region1003660DataSet.Tbl1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.tbl1TableAdapter.Fill(this.region1003660DataSet.Tbl1);
  

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried with a static variable then you should. I did the same when I wanted to show member id in another form to be printed on a printdocument, and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

What happens with your Form2 is `btnSearch_Click` is finished? Is anyone still holding a reference to it? Is it ok for the garbage collector to collect Form2?

It seems to me that the operator types some text in a text box. When finished he presses a button. Form  reads the text in the textBox, and tries to find it in tbl1BindingSource.
When found a new Form should popup showing the found information.

Should the dialog box be modal or modeless? In other words,
while Form2 is showing, should the operator still be able to do things with Form1? For instance press the same button again? Or should he first close Form2, before editing the textbox again?

The latter (modal) is easier: while Form2 is showing, you can't access Form1

I haven't got a clue what you do with the SuspendBinding / ResumeBinding and your tables. I guess they have nothing to do with you problem. Try to avoid sharing data between to forms.

Form2 has two labels and two TextBoxes. Use visual studio designer to create them. Code will be similar like this:

```
public Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponents(); // also creates Labels and TextBoxes
                                // if not: create them here
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => this.TextBoxName.Text;
        set => this.TextBoxName.Txt = value;
    }
    public string Family
    {
        get => this.TextBoxFamily.Text;
        set => this.TextBoxFamily.Txt = value;
    }
}
```

As alternative: one property Person:

```
public Person Person
{
    get => new Person {Name = this.TextBoxName.Text, Family = this.TextBoxFamily.Text};
    set
    {
         this.TextBoxName.Text = value.Name;
         this.TextBoxFamily.Text = value.Family;
    }
```

In form1:

```
private void ShowForm2(Person person)
{
    using (var form2 = new Form2())
    {
        form2.Name = person.Name;
        form2.Family = person.Family;
        var dlgResult = form2.ShowDialog(this);

        // if you are interested in the result of showing the dialog:
        if (dlgResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Person person = form2.Person;
            this.ProcessPerson(person);
        }
    }
```

If you want to be able to access Form1, while Form2 is being shown, show it as a modeless dialog box. Make sure you close Form2 before closing Form1.

```
private Form2 form2 = new Form2();

private void ShowForm2(Person person)
{
     form2.Name = person.Name;
     form2.Family = person.Family;
     form2.Show(this);
}
```

If form1 should react on actions in Form2, add events to form2.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // read the text box,
    // use a separate method to find the person
    // show Form2
    string text = txtSearch.Text;
    Person foundPerson = this.FindPerson(text);
    if (foundPerson != null)
    {
        this.ShowForm2(person);
    }
```

Make sure a modeless Form2 is closed before Form1 is closed:

```
private void OnForm1Closing(object sender, ...)
{
    // before closing form1, close form2
    if (form2 != null) form2.Close();
}
```

Officially you should wait until form2 has been closed, before continuing: cancel this closing, subscribe to Closed event of form2, when this event is raised, dispose form2, from2 == null, and start closing Form1 again. The second time form2 will be null, so closing can continue.

Did you see, that because I separated the showing of Form2 from fetching the Person information and the button press, the button press action doesn't care anymore whether Form2 is modal or modeless, it doesn't care anymore where to convert the search text into a Person: it can be a bindingsource, like in your case, or a database, or a JSon file, or even the internet: FindPerson can be unit tested without pressing buttons; you can change where the information is fetched. You can reuse FindPerson and ShowForm2.

In short: don't do too much in one method!